# mongoose doc update failled

Tags: node.js, flutter, mongoose

I want to update the doc list  object  through elemeMatch but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
// player id is passed from other parameter
room.updateOne({ isPlayerReady: { $elemMatch: { playerId: playerID } } }, { $set: { "isPlayerReady.$.playerReady": true } })
```

but  it worked as:

```
const filter = { "_id": roomId, isPlayerReady: { $elemMatch: { playerId: playerID } } };
const update = { $set: { "isPlayerReady.$.playerReady": true } };

Room.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

and the file is updated but wanted why first try ode didn't work.

Comment: You do know those are two different queries right? In the second example you have a `"_id": roomId` condition but not in the first. Have a look at [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-with-multiple-array-matches).